# How to set SQLException Number

Tags: sql-server, sqlexception, raiserror

I'm having an issue on settin up `SqlException.Number`

On my Stored Proc i'm raising an error

```
--@number = 50001

RAISERROR(@number, 16, 1) -
```

I should expect that the `Error_Number()` should be `@number` but I always get 18054

Is there something wrong with my `RAISERROR`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the sys.messages table for error code 74601. if this is a user defined error, it shouold be added in the table.

for any error that is greater than 50000 should give you this output if not found.

```
Msg 18054, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Error XXXXX, severity 16, state 1 was raised, but no message with that error number was found in sys.messages. If error is larger than 50000, make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage.
```

Comment: I agree, error code 18054 maps to the error "no message with that error number was found in sys.messages"

Answer (score 0):

There is one small caveat: You can't supply a message on your own in this case. But this can be circumvented by adding an additional %s in the sp_addmessage call or by changing all mapped messages to your own pattern and supplying the right parameters in the raiseerror call.

Check there for more information:
[SQL Server: Rethrow exception with the original exception number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882788/sql-server-rethrow-exception-with-the-original-exception-number)

> RAISERROR can either reference a user-defined message stored in the
>   sys.messages catalog view or build a message dynamically.

Check for your error message exists or not using this:

```
select * from sys.messages
```

If it does not exists then Use `sp_addmessage` to add user-defined error messages and `sp_dropmessage` to delete user-defined error messages.

for more information follow [RaiseError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) documentation.