# Common exceptions while executing sql queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception

I have read that catching the particular exception separately enhanced the performance so I just wanted to know what are the  most common exception that might generate while executing any sql query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't enhance performance, but exception handling provides a good way to control code flow.

The best article (the subject is too long for an SO answer) is "[Error Handling in SQL 2005 and Later" by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling_2005.html). And shameless plug of [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761898/sql-server-error-handling-exceptions-and-the-database-client-contract)

However, if you mean in c# then there is really only SQLException.

As to what causes them, the main ones may be

- constraint violation (fails CHECK, duplicate/UNIQUE, no parent/FK etc)
- overflow and conversions (eg -1 to tinyint)